# How can you launch a service from a fragment and stop it from the same fragment?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragments

I am trying to launch a service from a fragment but when binding an intent the startService (intent) command does not accept me, so I have tested if I launch it from an activity if it accepts it because it takes AppCompatActivity features and has own context. The error appears to me when in a fragment I try to launch the service with a button.

````
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent =new Intent(getContext(), ServiceToast.class);
                startService(intent);
            }
        });

        btnservic2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent =new Intent(getContext(), ServiceToast.class);
                stopService(intent);
            }
        }); ```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey Please use **getActivity()** instead of **getContext()**

For Example (Call this from Fragment)

Intent intent =new Intent(getActivity(), ServiceToast.class);
startService(intent);

In Fragment Start your service using

getActivity().startService(new Intent(getActivity(), ServiceToast.class))

Comment: Cannot resolve method 'startService(android.content.Intent) 
with that change. I can launch other activity but not a Sevice.

Comment: please check the updated Answer. and accept if its working for you

Comment: Thanks, for all.

i can resolve with getActivity().startService(new Intent(getContext(), ServiceToast.class))